# Drupal error after creating new theme ,Undefined variable: hide_site_name and other similar error

Tags: theming

I am new to drupal theme . I have created a direcory `mytheme` and added `mytheme.info` to it and copied other files from drupal's default theme directory . Now after editing the `page.tpl.php`, drupal is showing the errors below .

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hide_site_name in include() (line 99 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: hide_site_name in include() (line 109 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: featured in include() (line 168 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 187 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_second in include() (line 212 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: triptych_first in include() (line 220 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: triptych_middle in include() (line 220 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: triptych_last in include() (line 220 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_firstcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_secondcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_thirdcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_fourthcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
```

After searching on google, I have found that clearing cache will solve the problem . But even after clearing my cache,it remains the same !

Comment: did you copy all the files from the base theme? try adding `base theme = themeName` to your `mytheme.info` (replace `themeName` by the name of theme from which you copied your files)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you copied the Bartik theme and put inside your "mytheme". 
Do you create new theme or just create theme base on the Bartik theme?
If you want to create the subtheme base on Bartik theme. Please add the default regions in your new mytheme.info like from link : [Problems creating Bartik sub-theme](https://drupal.org/node/938430)

You may also check the tutorial from [How to Customize Bartik](https://drupal.org/node/1114190). It's the nice tutorial for creating subtheme base on Bartik theme.